# What value does readline return when reaching the end of the file in Python?

Tags: python, readline

One can use the classic loop

```
file_in = open('suppliers.txt', 'r')
line = file_in.readline()

while line:
    line = file_in.readline()
```

to read through a file line-by-line in Python.

But what value does 'line' have when the loop exits?  The Python 3 docs only read:

> **readline(size=-1)**
>
> Read and return one line from the stream. If size is specified, at
>   most size bytes will be read.
>
> The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text files,
>   the newline argument to open() can be used to select the line
>   terminator(s) recognized.

**Edit**:

In my version of Python (3.6.1), if you open a file in binary mode, `help(file_in.readline)` gives

```
readline(size=-1, /) method of _io.BufferedReader instance

    Read and return a line from the stream.

    If size is specified, at most size bytes will be read.

    The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text
    files, the newlines argument to open can be used to select the line
    terminator(s) recognized.
```

which is exactly the same as the [docs quoted above](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline). But, as noted by [Steve Barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019414/1048186), if you open the file in text mode, you get a useful comment. (Oops! Copy-paste error on my part)

Comment: The docs for this used to be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: `TextIOBase` documents that `readline` returns an empty string on EOF; the above excerpt is from the description in `IOBase`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the
>   last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes
>   the return value unambiguous; if `f.readline()` returns an empty
>   string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is
>   represented by `'\n'`, a string containing only a single newline.

Comment: … and `readline()` will happily keep returning an empty string after you reach the end of the file - it doesn’t return an error.

Answer (score 4):

In a python console opening a file, *f*, and then calling help on its readline method tells you exactly:

```
>>> f = open('temp.txt', 'w')
>>> help(f.readline)
Help on built-in function readline:

readline(size=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
    Read until newline or EOF.

    Returns an empty string if EOF is hit immediately.
```

Each readline operates on the remainder of the file from the current point onward so will eventually hit an EOF.

Note that if you open the file in binary mode, with `rb` rather than `r`, then rather than a `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` object you will get a `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>` object - then the help message is different:

```
Help on built-in function readline:

readline(size=-1, /) method of _io.BufferedReader instance
    Read and return a line from the stream.

    If size is specified, at most size bytes will be read.

    The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text
    files, the newlines argument to open can be used to select the line
    terminator(s) recognized.
```

And when this method reaches the EOF it will return an empty byte array, `b''` rather than an empty string.

Note that all the above was tested with python 3.6 on Win10.

Comment: See my edit -- Python's docs for 3.6.1 no longer works this way.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code snippet from the question in a (Python 3) console shows that it returns an empty string, or an empty Bytes object if opening the file in binary mode.

Is this documented somewhere? Perhaps it is sort of a broad python standard?