# How is while loop working in the python code below?

Tags: python, while-loop

How is this while loop working?

```py
myfile = open(r'E:\poem.txt',"r")
str=" " 
while str: 
    str = myfile.readline() 
    print(str,end=" ") 
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Please reformat your code so it makes some sense.

Comment: I've reformatted the code. Waiting for it to be approved.

Comment: @Shir I doubt the formatting is correct, even though it's now been approved; `myfile.close()` is inside the while block; it is likely supposed to be outside the while block.

Comment: unindent the myfile.close() line.

Comment: We shouldn't be attempting to fix the question; the OP should do that, it is their code.

Comment: You should not use str as a variable name.

Comment: Agree with @RufusVS about the variable name comment. It is generally bad practice to name a variable with a name used for other purposes.
I did the reindenting myself since its not trivial to use markdown properly when you're new. The OP will probably get the hang of it now.

Comment: @0 0 The OP will not reformat their question unless the improper formatting is pointed out.

Comment: @RufusVS You did point it out; the edit should be reverted and be done by the OP instead. But, my expectations for the latter are low. Yet currently, we are presented with  possibly incorrect example code.

Comment: @Shir You can select the code lines and click the code layout button to format code properly. If that is not trivial enough, the OP should take some more time to work on their question.

Comment: Thankyou for reformatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myfile.readline()` returns an empty string in case it has no more lines to read from the file. This is the only case in which it returns this value. Therefore, one can use it as a boolean condition in `while` or `if` statements.

Hence, in the example above, the `while` loop stops when there are no more lines to read.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019304/what-value-does-readline-return-when-reaching-the-end-of-the-file-in-python) for further information.

Comment: `.readline()` doesn't return `False`: it returns an empty string, which evaluates as a Falsey value. Important distinction.

Comment: Please point out that an empty string as a sole test case in a while (and if) statement evaluates to a false value. That part is (now) missing from your answer, and is likely fundamental to understanding how the while loop (condition) works.

Comment: I edited the post. Hope this now suffices.

Comment: Got it. Thankyou for the explanation everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the best solution. Here's a more pythonic one:

```py
with open(r'E:\poem.txt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print(line, end=' ')
```

`with` statement will automatically close the file for you.

Comment: But the question is how the while loop is working in the original code. Not how to implement it better.

Comment: I upvoted this, but it is not really an answer to the question: "How is this while loop working?"